# Initializing a struct and assigning it's parameters within a function

Tags: pointers, struct

I have done some searching around and can't seem to find an exact answer to my question. It seems like it should work but it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
typedef struct stack_strut {
    Item* top;
    int size;
}stack;

void initialize(stack* s) {
    s = (stack*)malloc(sizeof(stack));
    s->size = 0;
}

int main() {
    stack s;
    initialize(&s);
    return 0;
}
```

That's a condensed version obviously. I was under the impression that I'd be able to modify the contents of the struct since I'm passing a pointer to it, so a change a make inside the function should stick around after it returns. If I use a print statement inside the initialize function to check the size, it successfully prints 0. However, If I use another print statement in main immediately after initialize returns, the size of s is now a very large number. Is it because I didn't initialize s outside the function? I have to keep it in this format because the main function supplied by my professor starts off in the same way:

```
stack s;
initialize(&s);
```

Comment: Ok, so I actually took out the first line in my initialize function, where I set space on the heap for the s struct. It works now. But I still don't full understand why? Is it because I declared s in the main function so it already had space set aside in the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you write `s = (struct*)malloc(sizeof(strucy));` it overwrites the pointer to s and you do not initialize the "good" object. You created an other one and initialized it (memory is leaked). You can check by printing the value of

The malloc is not needed the s stack is already allocated in main

```
#include <iostream>

struct Item {
    int nodeId;
};

struct stack {
    Item* top;
    int size;
};

void initialize(stack *s)
{
    std::cout << "initialize 1. stack at " << s << std::endl;
    s = (stack*)malloc (sizeof(stack));
    std::cout << "initialize 2. stack at " << s << std::endl;
    s->size = 0; 

}

int main() {
    stack s;
    std::cout << "main 1. stack at " << &s << std::endl; 
    initialize(&s);
    std::cout << "main 2. stack at " << &s << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

will output (see initialize 2.)

```
main 1. stack at 0x7ffca7c72520
initialize 1. stack at 0x7ffca7c72520
initialize 2. stack at 0x5566830b0280
main 2. stack at 0x7ffca7c72520
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually figured it out before I saw your comment, but you did confirm my suspicion as to why it didn't work. Just to confirm, I didn't need the malloc because the s struct already had space reserved for it on the stack, so overwriting it with a location in the heap means that the main function doesn't know that, and still looks for it in the stack?

Comment: The main fonction does not know what happens in the initialize function. Also remeberer that the s in the main is an stack object while the s parameter of initialize is a pointer to a stack (an integer).